# Java- Updating Return Data from a Class based on User Input

Tags: java, class, constructor

I'm not quite sure of a better/more clear way to state the issue in the title, so please forgive me.

What I currently am trying to do is change the value of a variable based on the user's input. Currently I am able to set a value depending on the input, however my program requires a loop where the user must make an input multiple times.

The issue I am having is that when I call for the class, it only returns the first input's relevant data.  Therefor while the user can continue to make different inputs, the data is never updated past the first input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hw6Wargolet {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); 
    String buddyName;
    String userChoice;

    System.out.print("Nurse: The Patient's first name is ");
    buddyName = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("You: Let's see, I should (C)hange " + buddyName + "'s bandages," +
                       "(G)ive " + buddyName + " pain medication, " + 
                    "(A)dd antibiotics to " + buddyName + "'s I.V," +
                    " or (D)ischarge " + buddyName + " ");

     userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();

     Buddy score = new Buddy(userChoice);
     BuddyScore finalScore = new BuddyScore();
     //the loop. essentially repeating the prompt for input until a score is reached
     do{
        System.out.print("You: Let's see, I should (C)hange " + buddyName + "'s"
                + " bandages, (G)ive " + buddyName + " pain medication, " + 
                    "(A)dd antibiotics to " + buddyName + "'s I.V," +
                    " or (D)ischarge " + buddyName + " ");

        userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println(score.getBuddyScore());
        System.out.println(finalScore.getFinalScore());
    }while(finalScore.getFinalScore() < 5);

   }

}
```

Below is my class which returns the data/value.

```
public class Buddy {
    private String userChoice;
    public int buddyScore;  

    public Buddy(String userChoice){
        this.userChoice = userChoice;
    }

    public void setUserChoice(String userChoice){
        this.userChoice = userChoice;
    }

    public String getUserChoice(){
        return userChoice;
    }

    public void setBuddyScore(int buddyScore){
        buddyScore = buddyScore;
    }

    public int getBuddyScore(){
        switch (userChoice){
            case "C":
              buddyScore = 1;
              break;
            case "G":
              buddyScore = -2;
              break;
            case "A":
              buddyScore = 3;
              break;
            case "D":
              buddyScore = 7;
              break;
            default:
              buddyScore = 0;
              break;
        };
        return buddyScore; 
    }

}
```

Additionally, below is the class for taking each inputs score and adding/subtracting for a total score

```
public class BuddyScore {
   public int finalScore;
   private int buddyScore;

   public BuddyScore(){
      this.finalScore = finalScore;
      this.buddyScore = buddyScore;
   }

   public BuddyScore(Buddy object2){
      buddyScore = object2.getBuddyScore();
   }


   public void setFinalScore(int finalScore){
      this.finalScore = finalScore;
   } 

   public int getFinalScore(){
     return finalScore += buddyScore; 
   }    
}
```

Any advice, tips, suggestions would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: could it be that you forgot to call `buddy.setUserChoice(userChoice);` ? Or what happened exactly in your loop? Can you put the loop back in, even if it is endless, so I can see?

Comment: Just now updated it. I also included the class I have for keeping the variable that allows to loop to end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things I noticed:

**1)**

in your `Buddy` class, in method `setBuddyScore(int buddyScore)` you do

```
buddyscore = buddyscore;
```

instead of

```
this.buddyscore = buddyscore;
```

(could lead to a mixup of member variables and parameters)

**2)** (edit)

In your main class nothing happens with the new `userChoice`. Maybe you could do something like this:

first change the `BuddyScore` class so that it would store the whole `Buddy` object instead of only the score. That way the `BuddyScore` object sort of *knows* that there where changes in the `Buddy` object. And then you need to call the `getBuddyScore()` method within the `getFinalScore()` to always add the current score.

```
public class BuddyScore {
    private Buddy buddyScore;

    public BuddyScore(Buddy buddyScore) {
        this.buddyScore = buddyScore;      // here you store the 'reference' of your Buddy object
    }

    public int getFinalScore() {
        return finalScore += buddyScore.getBuddyScore();  // here you retrieve the most recent 'buddyScore' from your 'Buddy' object and add it to the finalScore
    } 
}
```

Then back in you main class all you need is update the `Buddy` object (within the loop) to always know the latest userChoice:

```
do {
    // stuff
    userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
    score.setUserChoice(userChoice);
}while (finalScore.getFinalScore() < 5);   // here your finalScore object will add the recent score from the buddy class to the final score
```

This actually works. But be aware that your final score will only be updated when you call `getFinalScore()` ... maybe you should introduce another method to make the update and let `getFinalScore()` only return the already calculated final score.

Comment: It seems as though #2 was still needed. I ran it through and it now updates with the correct score.  Though I think you were correct with #3 in a way as well. Currently my totalscore is not being updated. Though I'm wondering if it would be better for me to put that in the same class, instead of using two.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have been incredibly helpful and even helped me understand why it wasn't working, not just how to fix it. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: I am glad I could help! And I agree, having one score class instead of two, sounds like a good idea. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

When you call this statement:

```
 userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
```

You are assigning that input to the variable `userChoice`. Then again you call

```
userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Which reassigns the new input to the same variable overriding the previous one. Try changing the name of the second variable, otherwise you're only going to get the same response every time.